# How to transform three chained callbacks (AJAX) to Promises in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, es6-promise

I have this code:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'a.php'
}).done(function(res){
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'b.php',
        data: {data: res}
    }).done(function(res){
        console.log(res);
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'c.php',
            data: {data: res}
        }).done(function(res){
            console.log(res);
        });
    });
});
```

As you can see, it's just three AJAX functions. The second one depends on the first one and the third one depends on the second one.

How can I transform this to promises to make avoid using the callbacks and to make the code easier to read?

Comment: This is already very similar to promises with the `done`/`fail` methods.

Comment: @Strelok slightly, but the callbacks are nested, causing tight coupling between the calls.  It's possible to write this much more cleanly without any nesting.

Comment: @Alnitak have a look at the deferred object docs: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/ you can chain `done` calls.

Comment: @Strelok yes, you can, although I prefer `.then` to `.done`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery promises it should look like this, with clear *separation of concerns* between the individual fetches:

```
function a() {
    return $.get('a.php');
}

function b(res) {
    return $.post('b.php', {data: res});
}

function c(res) {
    return $.post('c.php', {data: res});
}

function d(res) {
    console.log(res);
}

a().then(b).then(c).then(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to make ~~synchronous~~ *sequential* network requests (wait for the first to finish before doing the second), in which case you can do either of these:

```
//
// chaining fetches with .then()
//
fetch('a.php')
    .then(res => fetch('b.php', { body: res.json() }))
    .then(res => fetch('c.php', { body: res.json() }))
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => console.log(res)); 

//
// my fav, use async & await
//
(async () => {
    const a = await fetch('a.php'); 
    const b = await fetch('b.php', { body: a.json() });
    const c = await fetch('c.php', { body: b.json() }).then(res => res.json());
    console.log(c); 
})();
```

Edit: I assumed from the title of your question, you wanted the answers in Javascript (not jQuery). There's really no reason to not use `fetch`, unless you need to support old browser but.... well.. here's some Vanilla JS examples.

Edit 2: I assumed you need JSON, but you can convert fetch responses to text, html, json, maybe some others too.. [MDN Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: they're not synchronous, they're _dependent_

Comment: Gotchya. So, you have to do it synchronously if the third relies on the second, and the second on the first. The fact that it's dependent forces it to be synchronous.

Comment: No, that's _not_ synchronous, it's _sequential_.